# How can I filter certain element in a string

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2

**playbook.yml**

```yaml
---
  hosts: local_host
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: set-details
    set_fact:
      filter: "{{ lookup('file', 'tmp/task2.yml') | from_json }}"

  - set_fact:
      result: "{{ filter['msg'] }}"

  - debug:
      var: result
```

**task2.yml**

```json
{
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "wait_for_task": true,
            "policy_package": "Mills07_Simplified",
            "version": null,
            "wait_for_task_timeout": 30
        }
    },
    "item": "Mills07_Simplified",
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Task Verify policy operation with task id 01234567-89ab-cdef-928b-bef7e174fc7a failed. Look at the logs for more details",
    "_ansible_item_label": "Mills07_Simplified"
}
```

**debug message**

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": "Task Verify policy operation with task id 01234567-89ab-cdef-928b-bef7e174fc7a failed. Look at the logs for more details"
}
```

When I did the following,

```
  - set_fact:
      task_id: "{{ result |
                   select('regex', my_regex)|
                   first|
                   regex_replace(my_regex, my_replace) }}"

      vars:
        my_regex: '^Task Verify policy operation with task id (.*)$'
        my_replace: '\1'
  - debug:
      var: task_id
```

I got an error message

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'my_regex' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in
```

**Goal**: I want to get the task-id "**01234567-89ab-cdef-928b-bef7e174fc7a**"

How can I get this string **01234567-89ab-cdef-928b-bef7e174fc7a**

Comment: Unrelated: *task2.yml* contains a json, why don't you name it *task2.json*?

Comment: What went wrong when your tried to use the [`regex_replace` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) ?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, we can call save it as .json and .yml

It is JSON format. I just wanted to save it as .yml for simplicity

Comment: @Zeitounator I have edited my question. When I used regex_replace, I got some error message,

Comment: `vars` is not indented correctly. (as is your are setting a fact called `vars`). Moreover, `result` is a string. Why do you need to `select` (which should be done on a list) ? Simply apply `regex_replace` to your string. Done.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε you are a Legend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for a [universally unique identifier (or UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which has a defined format of `8-4-4-4-12` characters for a total of 36 characters (32 hexadecimal characters and 4 hyphens) <sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format)</sup>, you can use a simple regex to extract it.

It can be handled with the following regex:

```
[0-9a-f]{8}-(?:[0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}
```

<sup>*You can test it there: https://regex101.com/r/4Hs7il/1*</sup>

So, in a `set_fact`:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    uuid: >- 
      {{ filter.msg 
          | regex_search(
              '([0-9a-f]{8}-(?:[0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})', 
              '\1', 
              ignorecase=True
            ) 
          | first 
      }}
```

---

As an example:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    uuid: >- 
      {{ filter.msg 
          | regex_search(
              '([0-9a-f]{8}-(?:[0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})', 
              '\1', 
              ignorecase=True
            ) 
          | first 
      }}
  vars:
    filter:
      msg: >-
        Task Verify policy operation with task
        id 01234567-89ab-cdef-928b-bef7e174fc7a failed.
        Look at the logs for more details
- debug:
    var: uuid
```

Would yield:

```
TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  uuid: 01234567-89ab-cdef-928b-bef7e174fc7a
```